# Dealing with compiler erros using LLVM 3.1 and LLVM 3.0 at the same time in a team

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, compiler-errors, llvm

I got a question related to the error / warning behavior of LLVM 3.0 vs. LLVM 3.1 using Xcode for iOS Development. I'm working on a project with someone who is using Xcode 4.2. I recently upgraded to Xcode 4.3. The problem is that my compiler (LLVM 3.1) seems to be perfectly fine with some errors in the code that my teammates older version (LLVM 3.0) refuses to build.I can't be sure if my code builds using the older compiler. This leads to a lot of trouble using SVN.

Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) UIColor* color;
```

LLVM 3.0: ARC forbids synthesizing a property of Objective-C object with unspecified ownership or storage attribute

LLVM 3.1: No warnings, no errors.

How can i achieve to get the same errors and warnings as my teammate? We're using the same Xcode project. Are there ways to set the warning / error level on an individual base?

Comment: Well, one option is to choose the version of the compiler you use to build your product and have all the devs use that version.

Comment: There is a option for choosing the compiler in Build Settings but there is no option for selecting LLVM 3.0 in Xcode 4.3. However there is some kind of flag that can be set... Does it enable me to choose an older LLVM version? And how does it affect my teammates running Xcode 4.2? I don't understand how these settings are resolved for different Xcode version working on the same project file.

Comment: I find your example strange. Shouldn't it say `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* color;` anyway? (or `(nonatomic, retain)` without ARC)